# project a template to a distant descendant in Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-template

> I have a container that use a component (**a**).
>
> Component **a** using a component **b**.
>
> Component **b** using a component **c**.
>
> ...  Component **n** using a component **n+1**.

My template will be display in the **n+1** component, is there a way to directly project to that component  without having to chaining it through all the component?

Comment: Ok. So you are trying to avoid this, right? Template of some component:
`<A><B><C><div>my template</div></C></B</A>`

Comment: This will require some more code. Can you at least post your template which would need the required behavior, and perhaps also some kind of code which shows what you've tried so far

Comment: Without more details about your template structure and what exactly you're trying to project down the component tree, it's difficult to tell if this applies to your scenario, but I recently wrote [this article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-pass-an-element-reference-down-through-a-component-tree-in-angular-86b495a2ce57?source=friends_link&sk=d94166d5bb4ce1b1156d27e07a3a015b) about using a Directive and Dependency Injection to pass an element reference down through a component tree without having to chain it through every component layer. Maybe that's what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon little information, I suspect that you want the following:

```
<hello>
  This is projected
</hello>
```

Where the `this is projected` will be projected to a grandchild of the `hello` component.

This can be easily done using the `ng-template` and `ng-content` elements, getting the `TemplateRef` of this by using `ViewChild` and then injecting the parent component in your grandchild component. Another way would be to use a service, but the idea will be the same:

Parent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
    <ng-template>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </ng-template>

    <hello2></hello2>
  `
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @ViewChild(TemplateRef, { static: true })
  template?: TemplateRef<any>
}
```

Child:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello2',
  template: `<hello3></hello3>`
})
export class Hello2Component  {}
```

GrandChild:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello3',
  template: `
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="hello.template"></ng-container>
  `
})
export class Hello3Component {
  constructor(readonly hello: HelloComponent) {}
}
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-da5hfc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello3.component.ts)